# Does clooj evaluates line by line or by the whole line

Tags: ide, clojure

It seems when i evaluate the whole file it does not have an issue.

```
(ns ShipDataRecord
  (:import [java.util.Date]
   [org.joda.time.DateTime]
   [org.joda.time.Seconds]
   [org.joda.time.format.*]
   [semsav.RecordSplitter]))
(require '[clojure.data.csv :as csv]
         '[clojure.java.io :as io])

(defrecord Record [W1 W2 W3])

(defn read-csv [fname count]
  (with-open [file (reader fname)]
    (doall (take count (map (comp first csv/read-csv)
                            (line-seq file))))))

(map #(apply ->Record %) (read-csv "test.csv" 1))
```

However, when i evaluate line by line it seems to give me a problem.

Hence after evaluating the file, i ran this line in the REPL

```
(:W3 (first Record))
```

but it gives me a compiler exception of IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Class  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:494).

I have googled around but i cant seem to find the problem. I have asked this in another question but as the words are too long i have to create a new question

Answer (score 1):

In `(:W3 (first Record))` the symbol `Record` represents class `Record`. I guess from your previous post you just want to get `:W3` field from first record of collection of records produced by `(map #...)`. So all you need is to get this value right from `map` expression or from variable where you can store result of expression:

```
(:W3 (first (map #(apply ->Record %) (read-csv "1.csv" 1))))
```

or

```
(def records (map #(apply ->Record %) (read-csv "1.csv" 1)))

(:W3 (first records))
```

Comment: I would just like to ask if the value of :w3 is mapped to records now? Pardon my questions as I am not used to functional programming

Comment: Variable `records` contains collection of Record class objects that was created by `map` function. So by `first` function you get first object of this collection. And by `:W3` you get `:W3` field from this object.

Comment: Keeps on getting this error: CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: ->Record in this context, compiling:(ShipDataRecord.clj:97) 

Have tried to use this line (println(:W3 (first records))) but it doesnt seem to work too

Comment: In `(doc defrecord)` we see "...Given (defrecord TypeName ...), two factory functions will be defined: ->TypeName, taking positional parameters for the fields, and map->TypeName, taking a map of keywords to field values...". So I guess you didn't evaluate `(defrecord ...)`.

Comment: Even when evaluating the whole file by adding a '(println(:W3(first records)) ' should print out the value of W3 but it just evaluates without any output